# How would I stop my comparison when one value is greater than the default value?

Tags: mysql

Hi I've got a problem in my query. The main problem is that it compares 2 values and count it as it sees that it is greater than the default values. What I wanted is when he sees the first value that is greater to the default value it will stop and not to proceed to the next comparison. Can anyone help me with this. Any form of help will be much appreciated.

For example when he sees that the value in TS.`TI1` is greater than the default value it will stop and will not proceed to compare with the other TS values.

Here's my MySQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'late_cnt', employeeid, J.timein ,TS.`date`
FROM timeschedule AS TS
LEFT JOIN employee AS E ON TS.employeeid = E.id
LEFT JOIN jobgrade AS J ON J.id = E.jobGradeid
WHERE TS.employeeid = '1' AND DATE_FORMAT(TS.`date`, '%m %Y') = CONCAT(LPAD(2,2,'0'),' ','2014') 
AND (   TS.`TI1` > '09:30:00' OR
TS.`TI2` > '09:30:00' OR
TS.`TI3` > '09:30:00' OR
TS.`TI4` > '09:30:00' OR
TS.`TI5` > '09:30:00' )
```

Comment: I think you might need to use IF ELSE statement for this.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You've `OR`ed the comparisons together. You'll get any result where the conditions match. Are you saying you **don't** want results where there's more than one successful comparison?

Comment: Why `dv`? I think nothing bad is with this question. OP shown his efforts and the question is clear (and, more, answer can't be found with _just reading_ manual page)

Comment: @MikeW: yes your right, I dont want the results where there's more than one successful comparison? can you help me with that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is something fundamentally flawed about your question:
SQL is a *declarative* language, you are telling the DBMS *what* results you want, and (usually) you don't specify the way *how* these results should be obtained.

So given that it's totally up to the DBMS to stop evaluating the `or`-sequence after it finds `TS.`TI1`> '09:30:00'` or to continue evaluation. Most probably it won't evaluate the following expressions for performance reasons, but the results of your `count(*)` should be identical, since you are counting *rows*, not *fields* that satisfy some condition.

EDIT: come to think of it there might be some difficulties if one or more `TI`-fields are `null`, but then I would try to `handle the`null`-values (e.g. using`coalesce`) than messing around with the queries execution-plan.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the values of the TI fields and using `OR` to combine the results. This will select if any of the comparisons are true (since `true OR true` is `true`) You want `true or false` or `false or true` but not `true or true`. You need an exclusive OR operation, or XOR.

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'late_cnt', employeeid, J.timein ,TS.`date`
FROM timeschedule AS TS
LEFT JOIN employee AS E ON TS.employeeid = E.id
LEFT JOIN jobgrade AS J ON J.id = E.jobGradeid
WHERE TS.employeeid = '1' AND DATE_FORMAT(TS.`date`, '%m %Y') = CONCAT(LPAD(2,2,'0'),' ','2014') 
AND (   TS.`TI1` > '09:30:00' XOR
TS.`TI2` > '09:30:00' XOR
TS.`TI3` > '09:30:00' XOR
TS.`TI4` > '09:30:00' XOR
TS.`TI5` > '09:30:00' )
```

This will select a row if any one of the TI fields is greater than the default, but not if more than one are.

Comment: Hi thank you again for your reply.. I tried using XOR but it didn't work. it Doesn't count and outputs 0 only.

Comment: I set up [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7d8e/2/0) that shows the `XOR` working. You haven't posted your schema or any sample data so it's possible there's some other problem with what you have.

Comment: thanks again but the fiddle link is not working thanks

Comment: @user3492048 Looks like SQLFiddle is down for some reason. Try it again later.